# How can a member variable survive after local object being deleted when function goes out of scope

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I Have 3 classes: Base, Container and Entity:

- Class Base has a string member variable
- Class container a wrapper for a char * buffer
- Class Entity has a static function that takes as argument a container and uses its buffer to fill its static member variable called value

I Want to fill the member variable of class Entity as follows:

```
void setLocalCopy(Entity &e, const Base & b) {
  char buffer[2048] = {};
  copy(b.getString().begin(), b.getString().end(), buffer);
  Container c(buffer);
  Entity::setValue(c);
}
```

in setLocalCopy we initialize a buffer by COPYING the string of class Base into a buffer. We then instantiate an object Container with buffer and we Set the value of Entity. The problem in here is that Container is a LOCAL VARIABLE to setLocalCopy. When setLocalCopy goes out scope Container object will be destroyed.

In order to solve that problem I wrote setReferenceToBase function:

```
void setReferenceToBase(Entity &e, const Base & b) {
  char *buffer = const_cast<char*>(b.getString().c_str());
  Container c(buffer);
  Entity::setValue(c);
}
```

in setReferenceToBase I create a pointer to the _str member variable of class Base. Now since Base is created dynamically in main, it will survive till the end of the program or until I delete it.

The part that I don't understand How did the value of buffer survive also? The container object should be destroyed we leave setReferenceToBase. Is it because it is pointer to a member variable of class created dynamically?

On top of that valgrind showed no memory leak whatsoever.

## Source code Example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class Base {
    public:
    Base(const std::string & str):_str(str) {}
     const std::string &getString() const {
         return _str;
     }
     private:
     std::string _str;
};

class Container {
    public:
      Container(char *buffer):_buffer(buffer) {}
      char *getBuffer() {
          return _buffer;
      }
    
    private:
    char * _buffer;
    
};

class Entity {
    public:
      Entity() {}
      static void setValue(Container _c) {
          _value = _c.getBuffer();
      }
      
      static const std::string & value() {
          return _value;
      }
      
     private:
       static std::string _value;
       
};
std::string Entity::_value = {};

void setLocalCopy(Entity &e, const Base & b) {
  char buffer[2048] = {};
  copy(b.getString().begin(), b.getString().end(), buffer);
  Container c(buffer);
  Entity::setValue(c);
}

void setReferenceToBase(Entity &e, const Base & b) {
  char *buffer = const_cast<char*>(b.getString().c_str());
  Container c(buffer);
  Entity::setValue(c);
}

int main()
{
    Base *b = new Base("base");
    Entity e;
    
    setLocalCopy(e,*b);
    std::cout << Entity::value() << std::endl; 
    
    setReferenceToBase(e,*b);
    std::cout << Entity::value() << std::endl; //OK but I don't know why
    
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does `getString()` return a reference? Otherwise `b.getString().begin(), b.getString().end()` is not a valid range.

Comment: yes it's by reference

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux the trick is in the second function. SetReferenceToBase. how was it able to print "base" wihout any memory leak

Comment: *"How did the value of buffer survive also?"* What leads you to believe it did? Edit : `Entity` just copies the string's value into it's `_value`. It doesn't need `buffer` anymore. `_value = _c.getBuffer();` performs the copy.

Comment: that's what I don't understand. I thought maybe because it is pointing to str variable of base? I thought that if do print after SetReferenceToBase I'll get nothing.

Comment: A `std::string` doesn't point to anything external to know it's value. It's value is entirely managed internally. If you initialize it from a pointer it copies the string that pointer points to and no longer needs the pointer or what it points to.

Comment: Okk So even when the object Container is delete when function goes out of scope. _value will have the copy of _str.

Comment: Yes. `std::string` is self contained.

Comment: please one last question. in set setLocalCopy It's not the same right? We do get an invalid read

Comment: No it's the same. `std::string` is self contained always. It doesn't matter how it was initialized, provided that it was initialized correctly. Once you have a valid `std::string` it's value doesn't care about anything else in your program unless you specifically change it's value.

Comment: oh damn it. I actually wanted to use a char * instead of string in entity. I actually Got nothing when I replaced string with char * can I add to the question. Sheeshhhhh I really wanted to ask that

Comment: This would no longer have anything to do with the original question and would be off topic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187198/discussion-between-gringo-and-francois-andrieux).

Comment: well thanks a lot @FrançoisAndrieux sorry if the question was weird. lol ; sorry again I understood. This really really interesting